# PHP DOM :: The text next to the input

Tags: php, dom

I have this HTML:

```
<form name="some_form" method="POST">
  <input type="checkbox" name="formcheckbox[0]" value="true">Some label to get it out</br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="formcheckbox[0]" value="true">Some label to get it out 2</br>
</form>
```

So how can I get out the labels DOM gives me only the checkboxes but no text to indicate a label.

***EDIT 1***

HTML is as is, since it is used from external service, so I cannot edit him, but I would still like to get labels!

Comment: Have you got any previous attempts at this?

Comment: I don't see any <label> tags in your markup.

Comment: Yes i attempted to get by dom, tidy parse etc. but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no `<label>`s there. It is very poor HTML (it also has end tags for `br` elements but no start tags).

Presumably, you mean "The text node next to the input"

The only thing you can do is to find the `input` and then get [its `next_sibling`](http://php.net/manual/fa/function.domnode-next-sibling.php).

```
$elements = $dom->get_elements_by_tagname("input");
$element = $elements[0];
$text_node = $element->next_sibling();
```

(Since you have multiple, you'll want to use a loop instead of hard coding `0`).

Comment: I added edits, HTML is as it is, it's external service and I cannot edit HTML. I agree it's poor.